# Dropdown position issues

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, position

So, I have this code to show a dropdown on top of the div and not inside it. The problem is that when I roll the page, the dropdown block remains there fixed where it opened.

Is there any way to keep the block above the div, but let it move when scrolling the page?

Thanks for helping!

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7zmk3bLn/)

```
(function() {
  var dropdownMenu;
  $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {   
    var topValue = e.relatedTarget.getBoundingClientRect().y
    var leftValue = e.relatedTarget.getBoundingClientRect().x
    dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
    //$('#dv').append(dropdownMenu.detach());          
    dropdownMenu.css('display', 'block');
    dropdownMenu.css('position', 'fixed');    
    dropdownMenu.css('top', topValue + 30);    
    dropdownMenu.css('left', leftValue - 120);    
    dropdownMenu.css('right', 'auto');  
  });                                                   
  $(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {        
   // $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());        
    dropdownMenu.hide();                              
  });                                                   
})();
```

Comment: You'd probably have to use position `absolute` and get you top and left values differently

Answer (score 0):

Just change your position to absolute and remove the top left and right attributes. An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed)

```
add    dropdownMenu.css('position', 'absolute');

remove dropdownMenu.css('position', 'fixed');
remove dropdownMenu.css('top', topValue + 30);    
remove dropdownMenu.css('left', leftValue - 120);    
remove dropdownMenu.css('right', 'auto');
```

Comment: Also, looking at the OPs Fiddle, because you're using Bootstrap you can remove all of the JavaScript to get the desired effect. https://jsfiddle.net/megasmack/xwodwvbs/

Comment: @PedroSturmer if I make it like this, it comes back to the problem im trying to solve. When you open the dropdown in the table boundary, the dropdown is inside the div needing to scroll to view

Comment: @SteveSchrab i dont undertand what you mean

Comment: @TiagoAlves Sorry, I forgot to set my fiddle as "base." If you check the again link you'll see what I mean. Your example can work without any additional JavaScript. Bootstrap does the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change position of popup to : `position:absolute`

and add the position:relative to the `<td>` which is wrapping the popup

Here's an inline link to: check https://jsfiddle.net/vizwa/172p8hk8/

Comment: so it doesnt work properly, when you open the dropdown in the table border, it show inside the div and I need to scroll to see